# Django override behavior of double underscore relationship lookup in queries

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

My main ask: Is there any way to change the behavior of a related lookup such as `MyModel.objects.filter(relationship__field="value")`?

Consider this setup. I've got a one-to-many relationship with a custom Manager that filters out Books with `active=False`

```
from django.db import models


class ActiveOnly(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveOnly, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
    title = models.TextField()
    objects = ActiveOnly()
```

And let's create some data:

```
jim = Author.objects.create(name="Jim")
ulysses = Book.objects.create(title="Ulysses", author=jim, active=True)
finnegans = Book.objects.create(title="Finnegan's Wake", author=jim, active=False)

bill = Author.objects.create(name="Bill")
hamlet = Book.objects.create(title="Hamlet", author=bill, active=False)
```

Essentially, I never want to have to deal with inactive Books. Here are some queries to test various scenarios.

```
>>> Book.objects.all().count()  # expecting the 1 active book: good
1  
>>> jim.books.all()  # also expecting only 1: good
1
>>> Author.objects.filter(books__title="Hamlet").first().name
u'Bill'  
# ^ this is what I don't want to see, because bill's only book has active=False.
# I want the queryset to return no results.
```

Is there **any** way to change the behavior of the `books__*` lookup to include the additional filter on `active`?

Comment: I don't know how you expect good answers when you don't provide full details

Comment: I originally wrote the question very hastily at the end of a day, I updated the examples now.

Comment: Where is the date_deleted that you spoke of?

Comment: @e4c5, In the actual code that I'm working on I'm using a `date_deleted` field. The point you raised in the comment on your answer is that filtering on an indexable field would be more efficient than on a non-indexable BooleanField, but I wanted this example to be as simple as possible, so I chose a BooleanField. For the purposes of seeing if it actually works, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

In [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#manager-use-for-related-fields-and-inheritance-changes) the `Manager.use_for_related_fields` is deprecated in favor of setting `Meta.base_manager_name` on the model. See the updated documentation for details:

> **Model._base_manager**
>
> **Using managers for related object access**
>
> By default, Django uses an instance of the `Model._base_manager` manager
>   class when accessing related objects (i.e. `choice.poll`), not the
>   `_default_manager` on the related object. This is because Django needs to be able to retrieve the related object, even if it would otherwise
>   be filtered out (and hence be inaccessible) by the default manager.
>
> If the normal base manager class (`django.db.models.Manager`) isn’t
>   appropriate for your circumstances, you can tell Django which class to
>   use by setting `Meta.base_manager_name`.

The warning, not do exclude objects in the BaseManager still stands!

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access):

> By default, Django uses an instance of a “plain” manager class when accessing related objects (i.e. choice.poll), not the default manager on the related object. This is because Django needs to be able to retrieve the related object, even if it would otherwise be filtered out (and hence be inaccessible) by the default manager.
>
> If the normal plain manager class (django.db.models.Manager) is not appropriate for your circumstances, you can force Django to use the same class as the default manager for your model by setting the use_for_related_fields attribute on the manager class.

so you need to change your manager to:

```
class ActiveOnly(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveOnly, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True)
```

Comment: "Do not filter away any results in this type of manager subclass" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#do-not-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass

Comment: I neglected to mention that I did try using `use_for_related_fields`, and it had no effect. According to this issue, there is a bug with that setting anyway. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14891

Comment: I updated the code to include `use_for_related_fields`

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* I'm not sure if you can override the QuerySet class somewhere to get this feature, my only suggestion would be to add `books__active=True` to your queries.

I've added the code to a github repo with a test illustrating the issue if someone wants to take it for a spin. https://github.com/alecklandgraf/NonDeletableDjangoModel

**Original post:**

I think you may need to set the `default_manager` in your `Book` model, and I would add a second model manager to query the inactive books.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
    title = models.TextField()
    objects = ActiveOnly()
    # try adding the following...
    default_manager = ActiveOnly()
    inactive_objects = models.Manager()
```

I rebuilt your example and found it to be the same for Django 1.8 and 1.9. Of interest would be the queries that are created as you've illustrated. You can see the added `"active" = True` in the `WHERE` clause of the `Book` query but not the `Author` query.

I'll noodle on this for a while.

```
In [1]: Book.objects.filter(title="Hamlet")
Out[1]: []

In [2]: Author.objects.filter(books__title="Hamlet")
Out[2]: [<Author: Bill>]

In [3]: print Book.objects.filter(title="Hamlet").query
SELECT "library_book"."id", "library_book"."active", "library_book"."author_id", "library_book"."title" FROM "library_book" WHERE ("library_book"."active" = True AND "library_book"."title" = Hamlet)

In [4]: print Author.objects.filter(books__title="Hamlet").query
SELECT "library_author"."id", "library_author"."name" FROM "library_author" INNER JOIN "library_book" ON ("library_author"."id" = "library_book"."author_id") WHERE "library_book"."title" = Hamlet
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change the behavior of `books__*` queries. I also tried setting `base_manager = ActiveOnly()`, no dice.

Comment: This won't work because, according to the docs, "Django uses an instance of a _plain_ manager class when accessing related objects, not the default manager on the related object."